# Excel function to Auto-Populate value in Column C based on the combination of values in column A and Column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have 3 columns with values filled in already in my metasheet. A combination of values in column A and column B makes the selection unique. I need to pull/return the value in column C for the values selected in columns A & B. for example: In sheet 1, I have the following data:

```
    country     Month    weather
1   USA         Jan       winter
2   USA         Feb       fall
3   USA         May       summer
4   China       Jan       summer
5   China       Feb       spring
6   China       May       fall
7   India       Jan       fall
8   India       Feb       summer
9   India       May       Rain
```

Now, say for a random row 25, I have A25 as a dropdown list with value selected ="India" and B25 as a dropdown list with value selected="Feb", in which case I would want C25 to have a **dropdown list** with the value in it being "Summer".

I tried this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B25, OFFSET(B$1:C$9, MATCH(A25,A$1:A$9,0)-1, 0, 2, 2), 2, 0)
```

But this one gives me an error: "The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column". 
I did refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/939760/auto-populate-values-based-on-multiple-dependencies-in-excel) solution. But I get the above mentioned error as the data validation for C25 is a **list.**

Any suggestions/ideas on this would be helpful!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sheet is set-up like this:

[image]

You can use:

```
=INDEX(C2:C10,INDEX(MATCH(1,(A2:A10=E2)*(B2:B10=F2),0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a second sheet with a matrix like following -

[image]

Here you will define all the weathers for country and month pair. I have used the default name i.e. *Sheet2* and filled the values that were available from your data. You will lookup the values from this for filling on *Sheet1*. *Sheet1* will be like this -

[image]

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$D$13, MATCH(A2, Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1, 0), FALSE)
```

Here `B2` is the month value, `A2` is the country value. `Sheet2!$A$1:$D$13` is the range for `VLOOKUP` and `Sheet2!$A$1:$D$1` is the range for `MATCH`. `VLOOKUP` will match the month, `MATCH` will match the country and get the column index.