# How to show multiple or all values in column C based on combination of column A and column B in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2016

Consider 3 columns below. For every unique combination of column A and column B I need to return the corresponding values(could be either 1 or 2) in column C.

```
  A       B           C
 USA      Jan       winter
 USA      Feb       fall
 USA      Feb       summer 
 China    Jan       summer
 China    Jan       spring
 China    May       fall
 India    Jan       fall
 India    Feb       summer
 India    May       Rain
 USA      Jan       Summer
```

Now, say for a random row 25, I have A25 as a dropdown list with value selected ="USA" and B25 as a dropdown list with value selected="Feb", in which case **I would want C25 to have a dropdown list with the value in it being "Fall" and "Summer".**

I did refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47408714/excel-function-to-auto-populate-value-in-column-c-based-on-the-combination-of-va) thread, It only returns me the **first matched value** which in my example is only "Fall". Although, **I would want both the values returned**("Fall" and "Summer").

The formula is used:

```
 =INDEX(C2:C11,INDEX(MATCH(1,(A2:A11=A25)*(B2:B11=B25),0),0))
```

Any ideas on this would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: You will need vba or a whole bunch of named ranges that are maintained manually.

Comment: I have a C# code that process Excel formulae to retrieve the values. Is it possible to do it using Excel formulas at all?

Comment: I looked into INDEX and SMALL, but I'm not sure how to use this and if its an ideal solution as they say we need to press CNTRL+SHIFT+ ENTR. and I am doing it in C# and not manually.

Comment: Yes there are array type formulas that will return an array of values, but I have no idea if array formulas can be processed in C#.  And, that is not what you are asking.  You need to change the question to include what specifically you want as the output.  You are asking x and wanting y.

Comment: Yes, My Question is: the formula i am using returns me only the first matched value, but I want both values returned. So is there another way to achieve this using Excel formulas.

Comment: And the answer is yes through array formulas using Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter, but you do not know if you can use Array formulas in C#.